# Copy folder when there is a file name error

Tags: vbscript, hta, long-filenames

I have a HTA file with functions in both VBScript and JavaScript. Problem im getting is that I have a VBScript function that copies folders from one location to another. Most of the time the function runs OK, except when there is a "long file name" issue. As I am using `objFSO.CopyFolder` call to copy the folder, All I am doing at the moment is checking if there is an error then ignoring copying that folder.

What I want to be able to do it still copy the folder. The solution I've come up with is to: copy each file from the folder to destination folder - then if there is an error while the file is copied over, I can rename the file (shorten the file name) and copy it to the destination folder - and stack the function to copy files from subfolders.

My question is, is there is a better way to do this in vbscript? or maybe there is another way to do this from within HTA file? (i.e. something in JavaScript)

```
Function CopyFolders(arrFName, strTempDir)
     Dim intCounter ' Used as a counter
     Dim intCF      ' Used as a counter
     Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   ' File system object

    ' Loop to copy folder in 'arrFName' array to 'Temp' folder
    For intCounter = 0 To UBound(arrFName)
        Dim oFolder             ' Object that holds the current folder
        Dim oFile               ' Object used in a loop for each file in a folder
        Dim arrPath             ' Array that holds the names of each folder in destination path
        Dim strTempPath         ' Object that holds the 'Temp' directory path
        Dim strFileExtension    ' Holds the extension for the file that is being copied
        Dim strDestFileName     ' Holds the detination file name

        ' Set default return value for the function
        CopyFolders = True

        ' Set the folder
        Set oFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(arrFName(intCounter))

        ' Let copy the folder to a temp location ...
        ' First we need to get the folder structure for destination folder
        strFolderStructure = ConstructFolderStructure(oFolder)

        ' Check that folder structure has a value
        If Len(strFolderStructure) > 0 Then

            ' Now lets check if requried folder already exists
            If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strTempDir & strFolderStructure) Then

                ' Damn! it doesnt. Well we will have to create one ...
                ' Before we do anything, we have to get the folders in folder structure (this is so
                ' that we can check that each folder exists) and also get the 'Temp' folder
                arrPath = Split(strFolderStructure, "\")
                strTempPath = objFSO.GetFolder(strTempDir)

                ' Now loop to create each folder in destination folder path
                For intCF = 0 To UBound(arrPath)

                    ' Lets build the path for the folder and check if it exists
                    strTempPath = strTempPath & "\" & arrPath(intCF)
                    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strTempPath) Then

                        ' It doesnt exist so lets create the folder
                        objFSO.CreateFolder strTempPath

                    End If

                Next

            End If

            ' Now that we know that the folder sturcture exists in 'Temp' folder, lets loop 
            ' through all files in the folder and copy them in the folder. We will set 
            ' Error to 'Resume Next' so that we can catch any errors that occur
            On Error Resume Next
            For Each oFile In oFolder.Files

                ' Lets clear the error and attempt to copy the file. This way if there is an error 
                ' copying the file, we can catch it
                Err.Clear
                objFSO.CopyFile objFSO.GetFile(oFolder.Path & "\" & oFile.Name).Path, objFSO.GetFolder(strTempPath).Path & "\" & oFile.Name

                ' Check if there was an error when attempting to copy the file
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then

                    ' Damn! there was. Ok, well lets try to shorten the file name and try copying again (this is because: mostly the reason for failure is long file name).
                    ' Before we do that, we first have to generate short name for destination file
                    strDestFileName = objFSO.GetBaseName(objFSO.GetFile(oFolder.Path & "\" & oFile.Name).ShortName) & "." & _
                                        objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFSO.GetFile(oFolder.Path & "\" & oFile.Name).Name)

                    ' Now that we have the destination file name, lets try the copy thing again shall we!! (clearing the error again)
                    Err.Clear
                    objFSO.CopyFile oFolder.Path & "\" & objFSO.GetFile(oFolder.Path & "\" & oFile.Name).ShortName, _
                                    objFSO.GetFolder(strTempPath).Path & "\" & strDestFileName

                    ' Lets hope that it worked this time
                    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

                        ' Alas .. no joy. Well the only thing we can do is stop copying files and clear the array item
                        arrFName(intCounter) = ""

                        ' Now set the return value to false and exit loop
                        CopyFolders = False
                        Exit For

                    End If

                End If

            Next

            ' Lets reset error handling
            On Error Goto 0

            ' Now we have to check for subfolder. So lets check if there are sub folders and function return value is true
            If (oFolder.SubFolders.Count > 0) And (CopyFolders = True) Then

                ' There are subfolders. We have to capture subfolder names
                Dim arrSubFolders       ' Array That holds the subfolders
                Dim oSubFolder          ' Object to holds subfolder

                ' Lets loop through all subfolders and capture there names in an array
                For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders

                    If IsArray(arrSubFolders) Then
                        ReDim Preserve arrSubFolders(Ubound(arrSubFolders) + 1)
                    Else
                        ReDim arrSubFolders(1)
                    End If
                    arrSubFolders(Ubound(arrSubFolders) - 1) = oSubFolder.Path

                Next

                ' Last item in the subfolder array will always be empty so lets clear it
                ReDim Preserve arrSubFolders(Ubound(arrSubFolders) - 1)

                ' Now lets call the function again so that we can copy files from subfolders
                If Not CopyFolders(arrSubFolders, strTempDir) Then

                    ' It looks like there was a problem copying files in subfolders to set the return value and clear array item
                    arrFName(intCounter) = ""
                    CopyFolders = False

                End If

                ' And now lets clear the subfolder array
                Erase arrSubFolders
                Set arrSubFolders = Nothing

            End If

        End If

        ' Clear object
        Set oFolder = Nothing

    Next

    ' Clear object
    Set objFSO = Nothing

End Function
```

Hi, As this has been marked as duplicate, I just wanted to put a quick explanation of why I started a new question. Firstly when I did a search (and it is very possible that my search was not very good) I did not find that post. But also looking at it, answers suggested are more command line options whereas I was looking for something in an HTA file. Saying that, if I had found that post, I would have started my query on that post so I do understand the duplicate tag.

Comment: Post the code you have so far and I will try to help.

Comment: @RandySchuman Thanks for the reply. I have added the function above. It doesn't cater for long directory path but is able to deal with long file names